# Android Studio library runtime error Stub! at com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver.<init>()

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, amazon-device-messaging

I have android-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar in the libs folder of my android library project. In my main project I am using this library project, when I am trying to run the program, I am getting the Stub error. Although I used the provided scope, the jar is included in the main application. How do i fix this am I doing anything wrong here. I am using grade 2.2 and Android Studio 1.0

```
my-library-project:

    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
        provided files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
    }
```

This is my main application which uses the library project

```
my-main-application:
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
            compile project(':my-library-project')
        }
```

Comment: Are you running it on an Amazon device? Those are going to be the only ones that have the library.

Comment: Yes this is on kindle